# How to position divs in html with percents

Tags: html, css, mobile, position

```
<div style="position:absolute; top:60px; left:600px">
        <h2>Shop</h2>
    </div>
```

How do you position divs in html and css using percents? As shown above, so far to position divs in html, I've been telling the pixels its located at. The problem is, when I tried my site on a mobile device, with fewer pixels, I had to scroll to see the whole thing. Is there a way to use percents to locate where a div should be, so you don't need to scroll? I can use CSS. Thanks.

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question; but, If you are able to, for the project you are working on, maybe look into Bootstrap or CSS Flexbox or CSS Grid. These CSS frameworks should help you with responsive HTML that will work on mobile devices as well as desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use percent and the layout will automatically change as per the screen size.

```html
<div style="position:absolute; top:5%; left:26%">
  <h2>Shop</h2>
</div>
```

In the above code, the shop will always appear `5%` from the top and `26%` from the left with respect to the size of the device.

But the problem with this approach is you will start seeing a lot of white space of wider screens. A better approach would be to use media queries to style the page differently for what will look good on each screen rather than letting css handle it for you. You could also go with frameworks like bootstrap which allows you to set the breakpoint at which you can switch to a different layout for different screen sizes.